# salt config.get doesn't return the package installation status

Tags: saltstack

I have installed `nodejs` on my salt-minion (Centos 6.6) using `init.sls` as,

```
manager-requirements:
  pkg.latest:
    - pkgs:
      - nodejs
```

On minion, `nodejs` is installed and i am able to use it.

When i run `config.get` on `salt-master` to get the installation status, it returns blank entries.

```
salt '*' config.get pkg:nodejs
```

returns,

```
Minion-host-name:
```

I expected nodejs installation status as `True` in the return value but it is not there.

Is `config.get` the right interface to inquire about the installed packages in minions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[salt.modules.config](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.config.html#salt.modules.config.get) is about the state of salt minion/master,  you want [salt.modules.pkg](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.pkg.html)

```
salt '*' pkg.version nodejs python ruby    
salt '*' pkg.install nodejs
salt '*' pkg.install pkgs='["nodejs","python", "ruby"]'
```

Full docs are under the packager specific module: [apt](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.aptpkg.html), [yum](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.win_pkg.html), [brew](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.brew.html#module-salt.modules.brew), [pacman](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.pacman.html), [pkgng](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.pkgng.html#module-salt.modules.pkgng), [pkgin](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.pkgin.html#module-salt.modules.pkgin), [ips](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.solarisips.html), [etc](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.pkg.html)

Instead of asking salt to describe the state of the system ("Is package nodejs installed") or to do something ("Install package nodejs.") the preferred salt idiom is probably to check or enforce the state file or single state in question (whatever/init.sls) with [state.sls](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.state.html#salt.modules.state.sls)

```
salt '*' state.sls whatever test=true           # does a dry run
salt '*' state.sls whatever                     # actually applies the state
salt '*' state.sls_id state_name whatever       # single state from whatever/init.sls
```

But to be honest the quick and dirty sanity check with [cmd.run](http://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.cmdmod.html#salt.modules.cmdmod.run) often wins out:

```
salt '*' cmd.run "node --version"
salt '*' cmd.run "dpkg -l |grep salt-minion""
```